# ExtJS change border color of focused elements

Tags: css, extjs

I am trying to change a default focus border color in my ExtJS app. At the moment I use ExtJS 6 and its default Theme-Triton...

Is there a way to modify CSS property to affect all elements and change focus border color from blue to red (for example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own custom theme that extends to `"theme-triton"` then you can create a SCSS file with your custom colors, like  `$form-field-focus-border-color: #ff1744` to change the border color of the focused items in a form

Checkout on how to create the custom theme [here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/guides/core_concepts/theming.html)

Otherwise, if you don't want to create your own theme, you can try to edit the css classes that are applied to the element you want to edit:

```
.x-form-trigger-wrap-focus{
    border-color:#ff1744 !important;
}
```